# RoR nested models not quite working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to tackle this. for the most part, it all works but when i try to add multiple songs, it only saves 1(the most recent one) and wont save multiple songs to the album model. I followed bates(revised) tutorial and cant seem to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_field", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@band, @album] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'album_field', f: f %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Album", f, :albums %><br />
  <%= link_to 'Back', band_album_path(current_band, @album) %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_album_field.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :content, "Album" %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br />
  <%= f.label :content, "Comment" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :comment %><br />
  <%= f.fields_for :songs do |builder| %><br />
    <%= render 'song_field', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Song", f, :songs %><br />
</fieldset>
```

**_song_field.html.erb**

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :content, "Song" %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
  <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the **application_helper.rb** i changed:

```
new_object = f.object
```

to

```
new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
```

and now all is well.